# Creating object in Sinatra app that maintains data on new HTTP requests

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm building a very simple app using Sinatra. I am not required to use persistent storage so I'm not using a database; however, I want to keep an object that contains a record of all my transactions. The object should not reinitialize when there is a new HTTP request.

I have tried putting a `@transactions` variable into an `initialize` method and I've tried `set :transactions, Transactions.new`, both in my controller (neither of which worked). I just tried

```
configure do
    @@transactions = Transactions.new
end
```

and it's still saying the object is nil (the Transactions initialize method doesn't use params and initializes all instance variables, so nothing should be nil).

Are there other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you considered using Singleton? https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html

Comment: @MoH. Thanks! I just tried it but it's still getting rid of all the previous data on a new HTTP request :(

Answer (score 0):

What you want *is persistent storage*. I know that you're trying to avoid it but you should perhaps just bite the bullet.

You could invent one from scratch like for example using a JSON file on the file system but thats not really going to save you any time. Better yet is to use a memory based storage like memcached, or an actual database like SQLite.

Using a class variable is a dead end since they are not thread safe and will not actually persist after the program ends.

Comment: The requirements specifically say "We don’t expect you to use any durable data store. Storing transactions in memory is acceptable for the exercise", but the app is required to accept HTTP requests and return responses. I guess I don't understand how both are possible?

Comment: Memory stores such as Redis and Memcached run outside of your web server so the storage is not tied to any specific request or even a specific instance of the web server. Anything that you store in Ruby will be deleted as soon as the program ends or its garbage collected.